# How to draw multiple objects in succession one after another in Processing?

Tags: processing

I would like to draw a single object for say 2 seconds, then draw the next object. I want to save each object so I can assess them after they each have run.

```
Object [] objects;
float starttime;

void setup() {
  size (1600, 1000);
  objects= new Object [100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    objects[i] = new Object();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //This makes multiple objects at once
    while (2000 + starttime > millis()) { //This is my attempt at having them run one after the other
      objects[i].makeobject();
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much apprecieated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a Timer. Processing has the [millis()](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html) which tells you how long the sketch has been running. A long time ago I wrote a class to use as timer, here's the code for that class and also a simple demonstration with a rectangle moving with a 2 seconds delay.

[image: 2 seconds delay]

```
class Delay {
  int limit;
  
  Delay (int l) {
    limit = millis() + l;
  }
  
  boolean expired () {  
    return millis() > limit;
  }
}

Delay timer;
int xpos = 0;
void setup() {
  size (400, 100);
  timer = new Delay(2000);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  
  if(timer.expired()) {
    xpos += 100;
    timer = new Delay(2000);
  }  
  rect(xpos, 0, 99, 99);
}
```

Hope this helps. Have fun!